# In what sense does continuity hold for unbounded functional calculus?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, functional-calculus

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Schwartz function. Let $I$ be the identity operator on some separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and $A$ be an unbounded self-adjoint operator on $\mathcal{H}$.

Then, $I+xA$ is self-adjoint for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(I+xA)$ is a bounded operator on $\mathcal{H}$. However, is there any continuity or smoothness available for $f(I+xA)$ with respect to $x$?

For example, as $x \to 0$, does $f(I+xA)$ converge to $f(I)$ in any sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $f(I+xA)$ converges to $f(I)$ in the **strong operator topology**, meaning that  $f(I+xA)\xi \to f(I)\xi $, for every vector $\xi $ in
$\mathcal H$.

The fact that $f$ is a Schwartz function is not necessary and here is a proof that works for every bounded continuous
function $f$.   Write
$$
  A=\int_{\mathbb R} \lambda  \,dP(\lambda )
  $$
by the spectral Theorem, so that
$$
  f(I+xA) = \int_{\mathbb R} f(1+x\lambda ) \,dP(\lambda ).
  $$
Next observe that $f(1+x\lambda ) \to  f(1)$, as $x\to 0$, pointwise on the variable $\lambda $.  Writing
$$
  g_x(\lambda ) = f(1+x\lambda ) - f(1)
  $$
we then have that   $g_x(\lambda )\to 0$, as $x\to 0$, pointwise on  $\lambda $.
Therefore, for every $\xi $ in $\mathcal
H$, one has that
$$
  \|g_x(A)\xi \|^2 =
  \langle g_x(A)\xi , g_x(A)\xi \rangle  =
  \langle g_x(A)^2\xi , \xi \rangle  =
  \int_{\mathbb R} g_x(\lambda )^2 \,d\langle P(\lambda )\xi , \xi \rangle ,
  $$
which converges to zero by the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem, and the fact that $g_x(\lambda )^2$ is
uniformly bounded.

Comment: I see. Thank you. With the Schwartz function assumption, can we expect the norm convergence as well? Or what other conditions are needed for the norm convergence instead of SOT?

Comment: Uniform convergence is not guaranteed even if $f$ is Schwartz.  Consider the operator
  $$
  (A\xi )(n) = n\xi (n)
  $$
  on $\ell ^2(\mathbb N)$ and $f(t) = e^{-t^2}$.

Then $f(I+xA)$ is the diagonal operator with diagonal entries $e^{-(1+xn)^2}$,  so for $x\neq0$,
  $$
  \|f(I+xA)-f(I)\| = \sup_{n\in \mathbb N} |e^{-(1+xn)^2} - e^{-1}| = e^{-1}.
  $$